# VHDL: Why is '0' XOR '0' = '1' in my design

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx, vivado

I designed a Processing Element, which should should be able calculate two different functions, which have L_a, L_b and u_s as operands. B_l_i chooses whether one or the other function is computed. Implemented in my final design it acts not as is supposed to do: the problematic part is when computing the function (L_a)(-1)^(u_s)+(L_b), which leads to the calculation 1 + 1 = -2. To determine the sign of the output sign_g is used in this case.

```
entity pe is
GENERIC (
    q: integer := 8 );
PORT(
    L_a_abs: IN std_logic_vector (q-2 DOWNTO 0);    --Input LLR: magnitude
    L_b_abs: IN std_logic_vector(q-2 DOWNTO 0);     --Input LLR: magnitude
    L_a_sign: IN Std_logic;                         --Input LLR: Sign
    L_b_sign: IN Std_logic;                         --Input LLR: SIGN
    u_s: IN std_logic;                              --Partial SUM
    B_l_i: IN std_logic;                            --Select f or g
    L_out_abs: OUT std_logic_vector(q-2 DOWNTO 0);  --Output LLR: magnitude
    L_out_sign: OUT STD_logic                       --Output LLR: sign
);
end pe;

...




--G-Function:
comp <= (L_a_abs >= L_b_abs);
sign_g <= L_b_sign when (comp = FALSE) else
          dbg_xor;

dbg_xor <= L_a_sign XOR u_s;
```

I expect sign_g and dbg_xor to be '0', when L_a_sign = '0' and u_s ='0'. But during simulation shown in the picture below dbg_xor = '1'. Therefore the sign of the output is wrong. In the schematic it is a simple XOR with the inputs L_a_sign and u_s and the output dbg_xor. Do you have an explanation for this odd behavior ?

[image: During Simulation]

When simulating only the Processing Element alone, this odd behavior does not appear. It computes the right sign and magnitude with the same inputs. But implemented in the whole design (an array of such Processing Elements) it acts this way in this clock cycle, what screws up the following computations. But even when simulating the array of processing elements with the same inputs, the Processing Element acts as it should. Therefore it is hard to give you a minimal reproducible example.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried simulating a very simple design with only an `XOR`, as a sanity check? Since this problem is pretty baffling on the face of it, I would start with that, and then paste in complexity until it breaks again.

Comment: Your waveform is not representing your logic. Notice that `L_a_sign` goes high then low. The `dbg_xor` is going high and stays that way. (All the time `u_s` stays the same) My best guess is that somehow the code you are simulating is not the one you are showing.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: When simulating only the Processing Element alone, this odd behavior does not appear. It computes the right sign and magnitude with the same inputs. But implemented in the whole design (an array of such Processing Elements) it acts this way in this clock cycle, what screws up the following computations. But even when simulating the array of processing elements with the same inputs, the Pocessing Element acts as it should. Therefore it is hard to give you a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This has to be something odd in your testbench code (incorrect port mappings perhaps?) , so post that.